# Confused connecting to API in Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes, postman

I am doing a Backend rails thinkster tutorial that involves creating a clone of medium. I am at a step that requires testing the routes in Postman. Thinkster provides an API that has built in requests and pre-made connections.

But the tutorial goes from step "download Postman" to step "send request."  There's no explanation about how to initially start using Postman.

So the first test is to test if you can create a new user with a Register request.  I am guessing this is in the Auth folder of the API as there is a Post request called "Register".

I am not seeing an area though that suggests I can make a user.  All of the items in my collection are have a request Url that starts with {{apiUrl}}.  Example: login's POST request is {{apiUrl}}/login. And if I hover over {{apiUrl}}, it says "unresolved variable: variable is not defined in current environment."

Could anyone help me get going with these tests?  Below is a gif of my Postman setup as well as the list of tests the tutorial wants run.  I am sure I am not providing something that I may need to in order to get help on this.  Please let me know if you are not being presented with all info needed! Thanks.

[image]

**Test out Postman authentication functionality using Postman**

You should be able to:

- Create an account using the Register request in Postman
- Test the Login endpoint using Postman
- Try registering another user with the same email or username, you
  should get an error back from the backend
- Test the Current User endpoint using Postman
- Try logging in to the user you created with an invalid password, you
  should get an error back from the backend
- Try updating the email, username, bio, or image for the user

Comment: `{{apiUrl}}` is, well, your API's url. You can either manually replace it in your request (`your_url.com/register`, for example), or you can set the variable in Postman (see https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables or https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_globals)

Comment: awesome thanks.  I am kind of getting it.  So if I am running rails s and using localhost:3000, am I just supposed to substitute that in instead of the {{apiUrl}}?  I tried that and got an error 404.  The only url I can get to work in a request is http://localhost:3000 by itself.  But that isn't very useful... Could the project have possibly specified in another place in my rails project additional text that might be in the url?

Comment: Is the API you're trying to test running on your local rails server or is it an external online Thinkster API? If it is running locally, setting the url to `localhost:3000/route_to_test` in Postman should work. If this is not working, you might have made a mistake when defining your route in your `routes.rb` file (try entering the url in your browser and see if it returns a 404)

Answer (score 0):

My friend I will try to answer at least the question about `{{apiUrl}}`

This are variables that can be global or environment, obviously global apply to all projects and environment, you will need to select the environment in which they apply.

Now to make it work, do the following.

1. Copy the url to your API server.
2. Replace it with the magic variable between `{{}}`
3. Go to the gear where you manage this global or environment variables «lest make a local one»
4. Click on add
5. first name your environment however you like, the go to the grid and make a variable placing the name inside the key and your servir url on the value side. Then save.
6. Don't forget to select the environment where you are working.

Thats it now your {{variable}} should work. Now you can use this variables all over postman, they are very helpful. If you are using a JWT token, you will be able to assign it to a variable and the use it on your postman api.

[image: the process]